# Using multiple IIFEs in one script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, expression

I'm currently working on a script file where the original author has multiple IIFEs wrapped in one. The descendant IIFEs are written for certain use-cases. For example there might be one for search functionality, another for a navbar, etc.:

```
(function($) {
  (function() {
    var $search = $(".search");

    $search.on("focus", function() {
      // Do something
    });
  }());

  (function() {
    var $nav     = $(".nav"),
        $navLink = $(".nav__link");

    $navLink.on("click", function() {
      // Do something
    });
  }());

  // More IIFEs
}(jQuery));
```

Is there any benefit in doing this? Overall is it redundant to create IIFEs for every action?

Comment: You have to find a balance but sometimes you want to wrap small blocs of code in IIFE to make it clear that the variables aren't used elsewhere (and ensure there's not conflict if there's another one with the same name). Of course, every time some 500 LOC code could have been written in 300 LOC without loss in readability, it means some choices may have been poor...

Comment: The benefit is that you have a (somewhat) modular approach, but a concatenated file in order to keep HTTP requests to a minimum. That said, I would expect this to be an *output* file rather than something you'd find in your dev code.

Answer (score 0):

What the developer has done is purely stylistic approach. He separated the different parts of the UI initialization into functions which all need to execute. For further info why the developer separated them in this way instead of naming a method for each and executing the method within this context you will have to ask the developer himself.